# Measuring the mass of a wall

Tags: mass, everyday-life

[image]

Suppose I am given a task to weigh this wall. Neither can I uproot this wall to put it on a weighing scale and measure its weight nor I can place a  weighing machine below it.

What should I do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can measure the volume $V$ and density $\rho$ of the wall and calculate the mass $m$ from this using this formula:

$$m = \rho \cdot V$$

The density can be found by looking up a tabulated value for the specific material used, or by taking a sample of the brick, measuring volume and mass and employing the same formula as above.

It should be noted that the wall is of course not homogenous, it contains spaces with air and mortar, but for an estimation, these can be ignored or factored in roughly.

Comment: measuring the volume of a random shaped wall is no easy feat.

Comment: @Lelouch yes, but the wall in the picture is an assembly of three cuboids. It is simple to calculate the volume of such a solid